# How to use a dynamic ng-repeat depending on user input

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I need to use two `ng-repeat`: one shows car brands and the other shows car models. This last one should only present the models of the selected car brands, but I have no ideia how to do it.

My two JSON files have this structure:

```
{
  "brands" : [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Alfa Romeo",
    "short_url": "alfa-romeo"
  },
```

```
{ "models" : [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "brand_id": 0,
    "name": "MiTo"
  }, ...
```

And my HTML is looking like this:

```
<label>Brand 
    <input list="brands" name ="brand" type="text" placeholder="Select your brand...">
    <datalist id="brands">
        <option ng-repeat="b in brands">{{b.name}}</option>
    </datalist>
</label>

<label>Model 
    <input list="models" name ="models" type="text" placeholder="Select your model...">
    <datalist id="models">
        <option ng-repeat="m in models">{{m.name}}</option>
    </datalist>
</label>
```

I need to compare the models' brand_id with the selected brand's id. I heard about `ng-if` so i tryied this (didn't work):

```
<div ng-if="models.brand_id === b.id">
```

**Any help is appreciated :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an input when making a selection. You can use the select element.

To get this to work you need to first communicate to your app that something has changed. Try changing your first input to a select element and putting an `onchange` handler in it. When a brand is selected we will save the models of that brand to the $scope and render them in the Models section. We can use `ng-if` to display the Models selection, only if a brand selection has been made.

Going forward you can then use a similar pattern for when making a model selection

We can set the value of the select options by using the "as" keyword.
`b.id as b.name` means that we will display the name, but store the value of the id.

```
<label>Brand 
    <select onchange="handleChange" ng-options="b.id as b.name for b in brand"/>
</label>

<label>Model
  <select ng-if="modelsOfSelectedBrand" ng-options="m.id as m.name for m in models"/>
</label>
```

Then in your directive

```
$scope.handleChange((e) => {
// filter out models that are not from the selected brand
  $scope.modelsOfSelectedBrand = $scope.models.filter(model => model.brand_id === e.target.value)
})
```

EDIT: correctly use ng-options

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work... After a little research i found that ```ng-repeat``` only uses strings and not object, so ```b.id as b.name``` does not work :(

Comment: Well, I was using HTML's ```datalist``` and that doesn't support ```ng-option``` unfortunately. I ended up using another solution with ```<select>``` once I could not find another way around. But i will accept your answer, thanks for the help :)